# TCP Provider: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: laravel, xampp, plesk

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (SQL: select * from [mt000])

Error at connect laravel with my sql server 2014 on plesk host .
have pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv and pdo_odbc and odbc are enabled in php info version 5.10.0+15327

but on local by use xampp are same code and confirations read data not error show

who to run the connection on plesk host ?

What could be the reason for the difference between them?

Can someone help me?